# Increment a date by one day with each click of a button

Tags: vb.net

So on my form i have a label named lblDate and a button. The text property of lblDate is set at 'Sun-20-02-2019'.

What i want to happen is when the user clicks the button the text of lblDate will increment a day. For example when the user clicks the button once the text will change to 'Mon-21-02-2019', the second time the button is clicked will be 'Tue-22-02-2019 and so on. I just cant seem to get this working.

Here is the code i have for my buttons click event:

```
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = lblDate.Text
    currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblDate.Text)
    lblDate.Text = currentDate.AddDays(+1).ToString("ddd-dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Comment: You should pretty much NEVER be getting data out of a `Label`.  A `Label` control is for DISPLAY, not STORAGE.  Declare a `Date` field and put your initial date value there.  Each time you want to increment, you get THAT value, call its `AddDays` method and assign the result back to THAT variable.  Any time you want to display the date, you format THAT variable and display the result in the `Label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store your date in a variable and increment the values from there. As jmcilhinney commented, Labels are meant for display and not for storage

```
'Declare dt As a field
Dim dt As DateTime

'under the form's load event
dt = DateTime.Parse("Sun, 17-02-2019")
lblDate.Text = dt.ToString("ddd-dd-MM-yyyy")

'Under your Button click event
dt=dt.AddDays(1)
lblDate.Text = dt.ToString("ddd-dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: You should not be getting anything out of the `Label` into `dt`.  The initial date should be put into `dt` and then `dt` is what gets updated each time.  On that note, you're not updating `dt` at all.  `AddDays` doesn't update the current instance so you need to assign the result back to the `dt` field.

Comment: This also does't seem to be working. Error on this line: dt = DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Text) Says string not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: @BradenPutt I have updated the answer, the "Sun" should be seperated from the other part of the date with a comma not an hyphen.

Comment: Thanks, still isn't working. Says Conversion from string "ddd-dd-MM-yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Comment: It is now working perfectly! I had the dt variable set as a string and not DateTime. Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: Done! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an exact parse of your label text, Convert.ToDateTime is unable to correctly interpreter your format

```
Dim currentDate As DateTime
DateTime.TryParseExact(lblDate.Text, "ddd-dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, currentDate)
lblDate.Text = currentDate.AddDays(1).ToString("ddd-dd-MM-yyyy")
```

**However your starting data is wrong**. Mon-21-02-2019 is not a Monday and thus all parsing code inside the TryParseExact goes wrong. If you set your starting date correctly to Mon-18-02-2019 then the code above works correctly

Also, note that the format *mm* is for minutes, months are parsed using the *MM* format.

Finally, as other people are already telling you, all this approach to store a date in a label and then increasing it is probably the wrong way to go. We don't have sufficient information about the reasons behind your approach but if you can change it then it is better to have a global datetime variable and incrementing it instead of parsing a label. You use the label just to display the variable value when you need it in the format you want.

Comment: Thank you however it says CultureInfo and DateTimeStyles are not declared. Do i just declare them as dates? Sorry i am very new to VB.

Comment: No, CultureInfo is a class and DateTimeStyles is an enum both defined in the Globalization assembly. You need to add an Import to have it available in code. _Imports System.Globalization_

Comment: Or just replace them with their full qualified name _System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture_ and _System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None_ [See here about Imports statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type) and its effects on the naming of Framework classes

Comment: Thank you! Ive got it (mostly) working however the year value comes up with 0001 when it should be 2019. How do i change this?

Comment: Not sure how this happens. How do you initially set the label? Everything follows what you put there initially.

Comment: I just set it in my form load event. eg   lblDate.Text = "Mon-21-02-2019"

Comment: Found the problem. Your starting date is wrong 21-02-2019 is not a monday. Set your label to Mon-18-02-2019

Comment: Thank you. I am now trying to store the date into a variable when the form loads, and then having the label display the variable but it isn't working. I have: Dim Date As DateTime Date = 01-18-02-2019
        lblDate.Text = Date but it wont accept the value in the value '01-18-02-2019'. Should the date variable be a string or datetime? It doesn't seem to work with either

Comment: 01-18-02-2019 is not a date. What does it mean for you?

Comment: Okay i now have the variable working. The problem now is the label isn't updating every time the button is clicked, only once.  The code i have now is: Dim CurrentDate as DateTime
Dim dt As String = "Monday 18 February, 2019"

And for my button click event: DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "dddd dd MMMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, CurrentDate)
        lblDate.Text = CurrentDate.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd dd MMMM, yyyy")

Comment: What is your culture? If your culture is different from en-US or other with english names for days and months then you cannot parse that string

Comment: I’m in New Zealand. Is there a way to do it without the culture info, current culture classes?

Comment: _CurrentDate.AddDays(1)_ produces a new date. It doesn't change the CurrentDate variable. So you display it once correctly but when you call it again the _CurrentDate_ is still the initial value. You should write _CurrentDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(1)_ and then _lblDate.Text = CurrentDate.ToString("dddd dd MMMM, yyyy")_

Comment: I have changed the code but it is still doing the same thing. Only works once when you click the button.

Answer (score -1):

```
'Put whatever initial value here that is appropriate.
Private dateValue As Date = Dwte.Today

Private Sub IncrementDate()
    dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(1)

    lblDate.Text = dateValue.ToString("ddd-dd-MM-yyyy")
End Sub
```

As you can see, there's no parsing to be done so you can't possibly use an invalid date.

You might want to display the initial date in the `Label` in the `Load` event handler of the form too.

Note also that you are using "mm" in your original code, which is for minutes.  "MM" is for months.